# Force fontification of another buffer

Tags: emacs, font-lock

Let us assume I have registered a function as fontification in a buffer named `foo`.

With *jit-lock-mode*:

```
(jit-lock-register #'(lambda (start end)
           (message "Jit!")))
```

From another buffer, I would like to force that fontification function (and all registered fontification functions).

I am using the function `font-lock-flush`, in the following:

```
(with-current-buffer "foo"
  (font-lock-flush))
```

Without any success.
That is, when I evaluate `(with-current-buffer "foo"...)` in a buffer different from `foo`, no message is printed.

I would expect that expression forces the anonymous function registered as fontification in buffer `foo`. Instead, the function is not invoked -- I don't see any message in the `*Message*` buffer.

---

*Additional Notes*
*I have also tried other functions to force, such as: `jit-lock-fontify-now`. Still, no message is printed*.

---

#### How to reproduce

Simply, open two buffer: `foo` and `bar`.

The content of `foo`:

```
(jit-lock-register #'(lambda (start end)
           (message "Jit!")))
```

And evaluate the buffer.

Now, every time the buffer needs to be fontified a message (`"Jit!"` will be printed).

Instead, the content of the buffer `bar`:

```
(with-current-buffer "foo"
  (font-lock-flush))  ;; or jit-lock-fontify-now
```

Evaluate (from the buffer `bar`) that expression.
You should notice no message is printed, despite the fact that expression should force the fontification inside `foo`.

Comment: Please clarify "without any success" (especially w.r.t `jit-lock-fontify-now` which would otherwise by my answer).

Comment: @Stefan The lambda seems not to be called. I would expect a message in the `*Message*` buffer. In other words, when I evaluate `(with-current-buffer "foo"...)` in a buffer different than `foo`, no message is printed

Comment: Please clarify it *in your question* rather than in a comment, and please clarify if you see the same thing with `jit-lock-fontify-now`, and if so please give a more detailed recipe.

Comment: @Stefan added to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jit-lock-refontify is a compiled Lisp function in ‘jit-lock.el’.

(jit-lock-refontify &optional BEG END)

Force refontification of the region BEG..END (default whole buffer).
```

Experimentally, this does what you want:

```el
(with-current-buffer "foo"
  (jit-lock-refontify))
```

Answer (score 0):

After running `jit-lock-register` in `foo`, buffer `foo` is marked as fully "jit-locked" (more specifically, it's done in the redisplay cycle that immediately follows, and it's done because the buffer is presumably fully displayed).  Running `jit-lock-fontify-now` after that will do nothing because there's nothing there that needs to be "jit-locked".  Running `font-lock-flush` won't make a difference either because presumably `foo` is in `fundamental-mode` so `font-lock-mode` is not enabled so `font-lock-flush` sees that there's no font-lock highlighting applied yet, and hence nothing to flush.

Comment: `font-lock-mode` is enabled in `foo` buffer. However, do you have suggestions to approach this scenario and force re-fontification of a buffer?

Comment: @BiagioFesta: The fact that `font-lock-mode` is non-nil is misleading: in the absence of fontification rules, `font-lock-flush` knows that there's nothing to flush.  As for **re**fontification, `font-lock-flush` was the right choice and its jit-lock equivalent is indeed `jit-lock-refontify` (whereas `jit-lock-fontify-now` is for fontification, like `font-lock-ensure`).